# MongoDB WiredTiger storage not using two CPU cores

Tags: mongodb

As claimed in WiredTiger storage engine description, it provides an ability of better concurrency due to document-level locking. From [this post](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/whats-new-mongodb-30-part-3-performance-efficiency-gains-new-storage-architecture):

> WiredTiger scales on modern, multi-CPU architectures. Using a variety of programming techniques such as hazard pointers, lock-free algorithms, fast latching and message passing, WiredTiger performs more work per CPU core than alternative engines.

For some reason, my use case doesn't seem to benefit from this. I have a database with many concurrent writes (mostly updates), and this kind of load can't seem to overcome the limit of 2000 updates per sec. Here is the `mongostat 10` output:

```
insert query update delete getmore command % dirty % used flushes  vsize    res qr|qw ar|aw netIn netOut conn     time
     3   780   1936    141      42     3|0     0.3    1.0       0 717.0M 289.0M   0|0   1|0  433k     6m  141 17:16:32
```

Disk throughput is not saturated, `iostat -x 10` output:

```
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          20.56    0.00   20.31    0.10    0.10   58.93

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s   rsec/s   wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
xvda              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
xvdb              0.00     5.80    0.00  102.50     0.00  6188.80    60.38     3.46   33.79   0.46   4.72
```

Given all of this, I assume that the bottleneck is in CPU usage, which is always stable at 100% all the time for `mongod` process in the `top` (from the total of 200%, which means that only one CPU from two is used). 58% idle time from `iostat` also confirms that.

Are there any methods to determine whether the WiredTiger storage is using document-level locking and two CPU cores simultaneously as it should be? Or could this happen due to any reasons other than CPU capacity limit?

Comment: What's your OS/Linux version, and do you have any MMAPv1 collections? Does `mongostat` indicate any kind of lock contention?

Comment: @Will I'm using Amazon Linux (release 2014.09). No MMAPv1 collection in the database. How do I run `mongostat` to check for locks?

Comment: @artch Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342889/how-to-measure-separate-cpu-core-usage-for-a-process to see how to monitor the per core utilization of a process.

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using? The tools changed in 3.0, so `mongostat` may not give you the info you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Write operations are being done serial on single core instance. Read operations have concurency. This is what i have understood from my readings so far.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of mongodb client setup do you have and what kind of hardware?

In my experience benchmarking different mongodb storage engines on different systems, a single instance of mongodb can hit a wall pretty quickly on operations per second.

It can be due to a variety of reasons like a bandwidth bottleneck or dispatch time. To find out if it's dispatch time, you can try running 2 mongod instances side by side. If both of them reach 2000 updates/sec and use 1 CPU each then its possible that the time it takes for mongod to dispatch update commands is higher than the time it takes for your system to perform some of the update commands. Therefore there would be no reason for mongod to use the other cpu core because the first one is always ready for the next update (even if it's at the limit).

If you still get 2000 updates/sec total and they still only use 1 core between then would be a different problem, and I'd need to see more information about your system setup to take a guess at what it is.

Comment: Does it mean that dispatch mechanics are single-threaded in mongo? If so, can it be optimized somehow without sharding and messing with multiple mongo instances?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `top`, if mongoDB is the primary CPU hog, you should be ablet to use the `1` option, (press `1` after `top` starts) or use an alternate method as described here: [How to measure separate CPU core usage for a process?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16227480/2896420)

For mongo tools, this is version dependent (the tools changed from 2.x to 3.x, so how to use tools to view lock info will depend on your version) but `db.serverStatus()` should give you the information you're looking for. See [How do I see the status of locks on my mongod instances?](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/#how-do-i-see-the-status-of-locks-on-my-mongod-instances) for more detailed, version specific information. Remember to check that the version of MongoDB you're using matches that on the top left of the page (click on the version number to change the version of the documentation you're looking at.)